# Submodule importing primary module

Tags: python, import, module

First of all, my apologies if this question has already be asked elsewhere. I really searched for it, but didn't find anything.

The situation is the following:
In a folder `mod`, I have the files `__init__.py` and `sub.py`.
They contain the following data:
`__init__.py`:

```
print "mod"
```

`sub.py`:

```
import __init__
print "sub"
```

Now let's do the following:

```
>>> import mod
mod
>>> import mod.sub
mod
sub
```

But when doing `import mod.sub`, why is `mod/__init__.py` executed again? It had been imported already.
The same strange feature exists if we just call:

```
>>> import mod.sub
mod
mod
sub
```

Can I change the behaviour by changing the `import __init__`? This is the line that seems most likely wrong to me.

Comment: Why do you say "import __init__" in sub.py ??

Comment: Because the primary module `mod` contains shared classes that are subclassed in `sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace

```
import __init__
```

by

```
import mod
```

Comment: I find it counter-intuitive that this works. After all, we are in the folder `mod` already and I would have thought that the interpreter would look for a file `mod.py`.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually inspect what is going on by using the dictionary `sys.modules`. Python decides to reload a module depending on the keys in that dictionary.

When you run `import mod`, it creates one entry, `mod` in `sys.modules`.

When you run `import mod.sub`, after the call to `import __init__`, Python checks whether the key `mod.__init__` is in `sys.modules`, but there is no such key, so it is imported again.

The bottom line is that Python decides to re-import a module by keys present in `sys.modules`, not because the actual module had already been imported.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I found another solution playing around with relative imports:

Replace

```
import __init__
```

by

```
from . import __init__
```

But I don't understand why this works.

edit: This actually doesn't work. the resulting`__init__` is not the module `mod`, but something else of the type `method-wrapper`. Now I'm totally confused.